# linux script for restart jar if it crashes

Tags: jar

Is It possible create a script for restart an jar application if it crashes?

The possibility solution  could be create a Linux service to automatically start when the system reboots or crashes.
Are there other possibility, for example by creating a script?

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

while true; do
    java -jar myjar.jar
    sleep 5 # in case myjar always fails
done
```